# Turning a function signature into a type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have property that is a function and it is typed like this:

```
/**
 * Function that performs the validation.
 */
validate: (vc: ValidationContext, object:any)=>boolean;
```

The same type signature is used in the class constructor:

```
constructor(validate: (vc: ValidationContext, object:any)=>boolean) {}
```

So if I change the signature in one place then I have to change it in another.  Is it possible to define a type that encapsulates the type.  Something like:

```
type ValidateType = (vc: ValidationContext, object:any)=>boolean
```

That way the `validate` type can be updated in one place?

### Update

Per the comments I got a little lucky in this question.  This is how I implemented it (@cartant if you would to put this in an answer so you can get credit I'll delete it from here):

```
    /**
    * The type api signature for the validation function.
    */
    type ValidationFunctionType = (vc: ValidationContext, object:any)=>boolean;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'd declare the type exactly as you've declared it in your question: `type ValidateType = (vc: ValidationContext, object: any) => boolean`. Or you could declare it using an interface: `interface ValidateType { (vc: ValidationContext, object: any) => boolean }`.

Comment: Really???  Wow got pretty lucky on that one!  Thanks!